# Not Able to Use the Scanner Object on changing the position where I create it

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I just started learning java on my own and I'm facing a problem with this simple calculator program that I wrote.

In the first code, I get the expected output, if I input integers with `nextInt()` (operands for arithmetic operations) before taking the string input through `nextLine()` (the arithmetic operations, ADD, SUB, MUL).

That is, in total I take 3 inputs.

It checks for the conditions and operates according to the condition which is true.

But if I change the position, i.e., first take the `String` input (the operations) and then the integer input (the numbers), it does not take any input for the **String** (operations). It also doesn't check for any conditions.

That is, in this case, I am able to input only the 2 integers and not the operation string.

What's wrong with the code? I have run it in Eclipse and Netbeans and the result is same.

**The one which gives right output**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  { 

    float fnum, snum, result;

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What Operation do you want to perform?");
    System.out.println("Enter The Choice \n\"ADD\" -For Addition");
    System.out.println("\"SUB\"- For Subtraction");
    System.out.println("\"MUL\"- For Multiplication");
    System.out.println("\"DIV\"- For Division");

    /**/String a= input.nextLine(); // on changing its position in the 2nd one

    System.out.print("Enter the First Number:");
    fnum=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The First Number Entered is : "+fnum);

    System.out.print("Enter the Second Number:");
    snum=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The Second Number Entered is: "+snum);

    if(a.equals("ADD"))

    {
        result= fnum+snum;
        System.out.print("The Result After ADDITION of the Two Numbers Is:");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    else if(a.equals("SUB"))
    {
        result=fnum-snum;
        System.out.print("The  Result After SUBSTRACTION of the Two Numbers Is:");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    else if(a.equals("MUL"))
    {
        result=fnum*snum;
        System.out.print("The Result After MULTIPLICATION of the Two Numbers Is:");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    else if(a.equals("DIV"))
    {
        result=fnum/snum;
        System.out.print("The Result After DIVISION of the Two Numbers Is:");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    else    
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Case");
    }
   }
 }
```

**The Second one which has the problem**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  { 
    float fnum, snum, result;

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("Enter the First Number:");
    fnum=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The First Number Entered is : "+fnum);

    System.out.print("Enter the Second Number:");
    snum=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The Second Number Entered is: "+snum);

    System.out.println("What Operation do you want to perform?");
    System.out.println("Enter The Choice \n\"ADD\" -For Addition");
    System.out.println("\"SUB\"- For Subtraction");
    System.out.println("\"MUL\"- For Multiplication");
    System.out.println("\"DIV\"- For Division");

    /**/String a= input.nextLine();// on changing the place of this, goes directly to the last else case, takes no input


    if(a.equals("ADD"))

    {
        result= fnum+snum;
        System.out.print("The Result After ADDITION of the Two Numbers Is:");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    else if(a.equals("SUB"))
    {
        result=fnum-snum;
        System.out.print("The  Result After SUBSTRACTION of the Two Numbers Is:");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    else if(a.equals("MUL"))
    {
        result=fnum*snum;
        System.out.print("The Result After MULTIPLICATION of the Two Numbers Is:");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    else if(a.equals("DIV"))
    {
        result=fnum/snum;
        System.out.print("The Result After DIVISION of the Two Numbers Is:");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    else    
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Case");
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: You should either use nextLine throughout (and parse input to integer when necessary) or fire a blank nextLine before the required nextLine. Check this thread for more explanation:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are still on the same line. so calling input.nextLine(); Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.

Check the documentation for [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) method for a detailed explanation.

To achieve what you want you need to call nextLine twice. i.e.

```
input.nextLine();//to complete the current line
String a = input.nextLine();//To get the user input
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, your solution worked. I read its documentation but as I'm new to java, I have one more question, would my program have worked , If I would have used "print" instead of "println". Because then ,Is think there would be no newline character for nextLine(). Thanks once again.

Comment: Nope. print / println and nextLine are totally different. The print / println methods belong to the standard output stream `System.out` i.e. they are used to **display output** to the user. On the other hand nextLine method 'belongs' to the standard input stream `System.in` i.e. it's used to **get input** from the user. In your case the problem is with the `System.in` not `System.out`. [Read more here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)